# CORS - Api Gateway, lambda, and vue.js

Tags: api, aws-lambda, axios, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am stumped as to why I'm receiving the following CORS error when invoking my API, protected by a Custom Authorizer:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://....' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In my SAM template, I'm setting up what I think is required for access from my local machine:

```
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
      Properties:
        StageName: Prod  
        Cors:
          AllowHeaders: "'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization'" 
          AllowOrigin: "'*'"
```

When I invoke via Postman, with a valid token, I get a correct response with, what looks like, all the required response headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin  *

Access-Control-Allow-Headers  Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token

Access-Control-Allow-Methods  GET,OPTIONS

Yet when I invoke in my vue app with axios, I get the above error:

```
  mounted() {
      …

      const config = {
        headers: {
          authorization: jwt
        }
      }

      axios.get(‘…..’, config)
        .then(val => this.info = val)
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
  }
```

Not sure why invoking from Postman, everything looks good and works. But from vue, it's not.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools to check the exact request you're making and the headers that are being returned. As you're setting a request header I would expect this request to trigger a preflight OPTIONS request. Again, the Network tab should show whether that is happening and whether it's succeeding.

Comment: To add to what @skirtle suggested: When you look in the Network tab in browser devtools, also check the HTTP status code of the response. If Chrome doesn’t show it to you, then use the Network tab in Firefox. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK success response?

Comment: If you're testing with Postman, don't forget to add an `Origin` request header, eg `Origin: http://localhost:8080`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the response code. Turns out my Custom Authorizer was expecting a 'Bearer ' to be prepended to the Auth header. I was not doing that in my app and it was returning an authorization error. I was only settting CORS on 200.